# SFTP Super User with Transmit or Cyberduck

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sudo

i have an ubuntu aws ec2. I can transfert file with os X terminal using

```
 sudo scp -i /my-key.pem /path/to/local/file username@hostname:/path/to/remote/file
```

but i would like to use Transmit or Cyberduck to do this.
I can connect to my ubuntu server, i can read file but i can't write files it says

```
permissions denied
```

So if someone knows how i can use `sudo` with transmit or cyberduck?
thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to describe which permission is denied. Is it failing to make the ssh connection? Is it unable to read the source file? Is it unable to write to the target file?

Comment: i edit my question, i can read files but can't write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem myself,
With Transmit or Cyberduck we only can transfer a file/folder in the user directory `/home/username/` 
Permission is denied for others directories.
After this, you have to move your folder in command line using :

```
sudo mv /home/username/my_folder ~/my/path/destination
```